# jQuery Chain Jumping?

Tags: jquery

jQuery is pretty much a big selector transversing engine with useful stuff hung on it. With all that power I can't believe there is not a way to jump around a chain. Therefore I'm assuming I am ignorant in the manner of accomplishing this.

I want to be able to fork a chain in order to make a modification, and then return to the root chain.

Example:

```
$('#clone-container')
    .clone()
    .find('#clone-topic')         // fork
        .attr('id', 'new-topic')
                                  // return to root chain (how?)
    .find('#clone-body')          // fork
        .attr('id', 'new-body')
    .attr('id', 'new-container')  // return to root chain (how?)
    .append('body');
```

I hope that made at least a little bit of sense. :)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [.end()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/end)

> Revert the most recent 'destructive'
>   operation, changing the set of matched
>   elements to its previous state (right
>   before the destructive operation).

Comment: But can end() be called several times? Or are we locked into only one revert level?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('#clone-container')
.clone()
.find('#clone-topic')         // fork
    .attr('id', 'new-topic')
    .end()  // return to root chain
.find('#clone-body')          // fork
    .attr('id', 'new-body')
.attr('id', 'new-container')
.end()  // return to root chain
.append('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `end()`, but I think that is pushing the whole chaining thing a bit too far...

I think this would be the most readable way to do what you want:

```
var $c = $('#clone-container').clone();
$('#clone-topic', $c).attr('id', 'new-topic');
$('#clone-body', $c).attr('id', 'new-body');
$c.attr('id', 'new-container').append('body');
```

But to each their own. :)